# Adding foreign key to model in django 1.0.4

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, migration

I have django 1.0.4 and I want to add a new model and one-to-many (Foreign Key) relationship.
when I run the `python manage.py syncdb` command, I get the message: `Creating table blog_blogcategory.` Here is OK.
One, I do not have a `category` field in the Blog table. Why this is not working?

Here are my models:

```
class BlogCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Blog categpry'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Blog categories'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Blog(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(BlogCategory, related_name="blogs", null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: There is absolutely no good reason to be using a version of Django that is ten years old and completely insecure. You should upgrade as a matter of urgency. Quite apart from anything else, more recent versions include migrations; but you should upgrade anyway.

Comment: upgrade your django to at least to 1.11!!!